# Taking multiple values in an argument in Clap

Tags: rust, clap

I'm using [Clap](https://docs.rs/clap/2.29.0/clap/) and I'm trying to make it so that a subcommand can take multiple values for the argument. The interface I'm after is:

```
just use repo [files]
```

An example:

```
just use radar/dot-files gitaliases ryan-aliases
```

The `repo` argument here will be the string "radar/dot-files" and the `files` argument will be a vector of `["gitaliases", "ryan-aliases"]`.

Here's the code that I'm trying to use:

```
let matches = App::new("just")
    .version("v1.0-beta")
    .subcommand(
        SubCommand::with_name("use")
            .arg(Arg::with_name("repo").required(true))
            .arg(
                Arg::with_name("files")
                    .required(true)
                    .multiple(true)
                    .number_of_values(1),
            ),
    )
    .get_matches();

if let Some(matches) = matches.subcommand_matches("use") {
    println!("{:?}", matches.value_of("files").unwrap())
}
```

This outputs just the first file that I specify, rather than *all* the files.

How can I make it output all the different files, for an arbitrary number of arguments?

Answer (score 17):

durka42 from irc.mozilla.org#rust told me to use `values_of` instead of `value_of`:

```
let matches = App::new("just")
    .version("v1.0-beta")
    .subcommand(
        SubCommand::with_name("use")
            .arg(Arg::with_name("repo").required(true))
            .arg(Arg::with_name("files").required(true).min_values(1)),
    )
    .get_matches();

if let Some(matches) = matches.subcommand_matches("use") {
    let files: Vec<_> = matches.values_of("files").unwrap().collect();
    println!("{}", files[0]);
    println!("{}", files[1]);
}
```

I could probably use an `iter()` call to go through the files if I wanted to.

Comment: You may also be interested in using [index](https://docs.rs/clap/2.29.0/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.index) with [multiple](https://docs.rs/clap/2.29.0/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.multiple).

Comment: `values_of()` is deprecated and replaced by `get_many()`