# How to pass multiple values per argument using Clap?

Tags: rust, clap

Is there a way to pass multiple values per parameter using clap?

For instance, if I type this

```
$ ./app —-color red, green, blue -—height 100 200
```

or this

```
$ ./app —-color red —-color green —-color blue —-height 100 —-height 200
```

I should get this:

```
color: red, green, blue
height: 100, 200
```

I’m aware of the `multiple(true)` option, but I cannot figure out how to iterate multiple values like in the example above.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Taking multiple values in an argument in Clap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48068334/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Oh I missed that answer! Yup, it definitely fits my needs. You can set it as already answered.